# UIviewcontrollerproblem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

In my view i have Textfield.If i move that TextField it should open iphone keyboard occupies.Extra TextFields doesn't display

Please help in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the keyboard to slide away when you click outside the textfield implement:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [myTextfield resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: hello diederik hoogenboom u r answer very nice